# Conditional Assignment frame$col <- val with magrittr

Tags: r, variable-assignment, magrittr

What is the Magrittr syntax to assign Iris$column  based on Iris$Petal.Length ?  Example without Magrittr:

```
df      <- iris[47:56,]
df$val1 <- NA                                           ## create column
df$val1[which(df$Petal.Length < 1.52)]                         <- "cake"
df$val1[which(df$Petal.Length > 1.55 & df$Petal.Length <=4.55)] <- "pie"
df$val1[which(df$Petal.Length > 4.55)]                        <- "apple"

head(df)
```

This results in:

```
Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species    val1

1.6                0.2     setosa     pie

1.4                0.2     setosa     cake

1.5                0.2     setosa     cake

1.4                0.2     setosa     cake

1.4                1.4.  versicolor   apple
```

Comment: Why not just use `cut()`?

Comment: Not really relevant to the issue, but you don't need `which` in your example, a vector of booleans works just fine. (`df$val1[df$Petal.Length < 1.52]  <- "cake"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact equivalent `magrittr` syntax to what you wrote is :

```
df %>% transform(val1 = NA) %$%
  inset(.,Petal.Length < 1.52,"val1","cake") %$%
  inset(.,Petal.Length > 1.55 & Petal.Length <= 4.55,"val1","pie") %$%
  inset(.,Petal.Length > 4.55,"val1","apple")
```

Or to be really zealous with `magrittr`'s aliases:

```
df %>% transform(val1 = NA) %$%
  inset(.,Petal.Length %>% is_less_than(1.52),"val1","cake") %$%
  inset(.,Petal.Length %>% is_greater_than(1.55) & Petal.Length %>% 
  is_weakly_less_than(4.55),"val1","pie") %$%
  inset(.,Petal.Length %>% is_greater_than(4.55),"val1","apple")
```

And a variant:

```
df %>% transform(val1 = NA) %$%
  inset(.,Petal.Length %>% is_less_than(1.52),"val1","cake") %$%
  inset(.,Petal.Length %>% {is_greater_than(.,1.55) & is_weakly_less_than(.,4.55)},"val1","pie") %$%
  inset(.,Petal.Length %>% is_greater_than(4.55),"val1","apple")
```

The two first are strictly equivalent to this in base (except for the pipes!):

```
df %>% transform(val1 = NA) %$%
  `[<-`(.,Petal.Length < 1.52,"val1","cake") %$%
  `[<-`(.,Petal.Length > 1.55 & Petal.Length <= 4.55,"val1","pie") %$%
  `[<-`(.,Petal.Length > 4.55,"val1","apple")
```

The variant is equivalent to this:

```
df %>% transform(val1 = NA) %$%
  `[<-`(.,Petal.Length < 1.52,"val1","cake") %$%
  `[<-`(.,Petal.Length %>% {`>`(.,1.55) & `<=`(.,4.55)},"val1","pie") %$%
  `[<-`(.,Petal.Length > 4.55,"val1","apple")
```

I used `transform` because it's a `base` function while `mutate` is a `dplyr` function but they work the same way here.

For a definition of all the aliases see: `?extract`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
res <- df %>% 
          mutate(val1 = case_when(Petal.Length < 1.52 ~ 'cake',
                  Petal.Length > 1.55 & Petal.Length <= 4.55 ~ 'pie',
                   Petal.Length > 4.55 ~'apple'))
head(res, 5)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species  val1
#1          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa   pie
#2          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa  cake
#3          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa  cake
#4          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa  cake
#5          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor apple
```

Comment: I have found myself adding  %>% factor   between your last two ))

Comment: @בנימןהגלילי  Thanks, I was just curious about that, it is not about the rep

Comment: really thank you, I've been using case_when all the time since you showed it to me.